# Haskell interpret literal types written to file

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

Write a literal type implementation (ClientCore) to file. Using `readFile` returns a `String`. What would be the easiest way to separate this `String` and return individual `ClientCore` types? Bit struggling here (note: Haskell beginner getting feet wet).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

import System.IO
import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import Web.Scotty
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

data ClientCore = ClientCore { clId :: Int
                             , clName :: String
                             , clCore :: String
                             , clClass :: Int
                             } deriving (Show, Generic)

parseReadClientCore getFile = undefined

constructClientData :: String -> String -> String -> String -> ClientCore
constructClientData clId' clName' clCore' clClass' =
  ClientCore { clId = parse_clId
             , clName = clName'
             , clCore = clCore'
             , clClass = parse_clClass
             }
  where
    parse_clId = read $ clId' :: Int
    parse_clClass = read $ clClass' :: Int

newClientCore :: IO ()
newClientCore = do
  putStr "Client ID: "; clId <- getLine
  putStr "Name: "; clName <- getLine
  putStr "Core business: "; clCore <- getLine
  putStr "Classification: "; clClass <- getLine
  postClientCore <- return (constructClientData clId clName clCore clClass)
  appendFile "haskelltypes.txt" $ (show postClientCore)

readClientCore :: IO ()
readClientCore = do
  getFile <- readFile "haskelltypes.txt"
  return (parseReadClientCore getFile)
```

Comment: Add `Read` to the `deriving` clause, then you can use the `read` or `readsPrec` functions.

Answer (score 0):

[Read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Read) is the inverse of `Show`, and will let you convert one String to one `ClientCore`.

I think it will be easier to first separate the file into strings each representing one `ClientCore`, then reading each piece.  The easiest way is to add a newline after each when writing the file, and then use [lines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) to split the file.

Comment: Good idea. Did not think of escaping it yet.